# Update Apple ID to iCloud @me address

Tags: apple-id, icloud

I previously had an Apple ID account, and I logged in using my gmail address. Now I have a @me.com address and I'd like to use that to log in.

How can I change the address I log into my Apple ID account (e.g. when downloading apps) to my new @me address?

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

[How to change the name you use for your Apple ID](http://support.apple.com/kb/HE40)

1. At My Apple ID, click "Manage your account."
2. Sign in using your current Apple ID and password.
3. With the Name, ID, and Email Address drawer selected, click Edit next to your Apple ID.
4. Enter your new Apple ID in the Apple ID field. You should use your primary email address as your Apple ID.

You can change a non-me.com address, but you cannot change a me.com address to something else.

Do you want to change what ID you use for iTunes and AppStore purchases?

1. Open iTunes
2. Click **Store**
3. On the menu, you will see View My Account, followed by the account which is signed in.  If the account is your .me account, you are done.
4. You are signed in with something other than your .me account.  So, sign out.
5. Sign in with the .me account you want to use.  You are done.
6. Repeat as appropriate on the AppStore and on all your other devices.

Comment: It will not let me change to me.com address

Comment: I get this message:  You cannot create an Apple ID using a MobileMe account. If this is your email address, it is also your Apple ID.